# .Net: How to find unused Fields / DataMember in the class?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, datacontract, ndepend

I'm having more than 150 Datacontacts in each I've more than 10 DataMember. How to find the unused Datamember in the code?

I'm able to find by right-clicking on the DataMember and "Find All Reference" option, But this is not a solution to my problem because I’ve huge number of DataMember.

update : 
I've find one Vs2010 plug-in [Ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).Using this I'm able to find unused methods and classes but not DataMember.
I've tried below code in Ndepend but it is not working.

```
// <Name>Potentially dead Fields</Name>
warnif count > 0
from f in JustMyCode.Fields where   
f.NbMethodsUsingMe == 0 &&   
!f.IsPublic &&     // Although not recommended, public fields might be used by client applications of your assemblies.   
!f.IsLiteral &&    // The IL code never explicitely uses literal fields.   
!f.IsEnumValue &&  // The IL code never explicitely uses enumeration value.   
f.Name !=  "value__"  && // Field named 'value__' are relative to enumerations and the IL code never explicitely uses them.  
!f.HasAttribute("NDepend.Attributes.IsNotDeadCodeAttribute".AllowNoMatch()) &&   
!f.IsGeneratedByCompiler   // If you don't want to link NDepend.API.dll, you can use your own IsNotDeadCodeAttribute and adapt this rule.
select f
```

**screen :**
[image]

Comment: Please precise what you mean by DataMember? It looks like you mean fields of a class? If so, what do you mean by "the default rule Potentially dead Fields is not working" ? What makes you think this rule is not working?

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam, Yes I mean fields of the class.
I have tried the above code to find the dead fields, but I got the result as "No field matched”. Actually I have dead fields in my code.

Comment: So if you have unused fields with (f.NbMethodsUsingMe == 0) it'd be interesting to investigate which negative clause in the query provokes not matching them.

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam I've edited my question.have a look

Comment: I can see from your screenshot that the field AIRLINEEXCLUDE is a literal field. Literal fields are just constant value duplicated in IL code when they are used. Since NDepend analyzes IL code, it cannot see if such literal field is used or not.This is why in the default query we have the filter     !f.IsLiteral &&    // The IL code never explicitely uses literal fields.

Comment: I guess the negative clause that prevents you to see unused fields is this one, isn't it?   !f.IsPublic &&     // Although not recommended, public fields might be used by client applications of your assemblies.

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam..I'm able to find the solution using your tool.Actually I have Public propertics(used like fiels) now i removed all property keyword in my code for testing purpose.now your code is working Great!!

Comment: And Your Tool is great...Many Thanks @PatrickfromNDependteam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the Property Key word in the DataMember.then I ran the Ndepend.
I'm able to find the unused Datamembers.

```
Public Class AccountInformation
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property AccountNumber As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property OtherElementQualifier As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property OtherElementNumber As String
End Class
```

remove Property Keyword

```
Public Class AccountInformation
    <DataMember()>
    Public AccountNumber As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public OtherElementQualifier As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public OtherElementNumber As String
End Class
```

then run the below script in Ndepend.

```
// <Name>Potentially dead Fields</Name>
warnif count > 0
from f in JustMyCode.Fields where   
f.NbMethodsUsingMe == 0 &&   
//!f.IsPublic &&   Although not recommended, public fields might be used by client applications of your assemblies.   
!f.IsLiteral &&    // The IL code never explicitely uses literal fields.   
!f.IsEnumValue &&  // The IL code never explicitely uses enumeration value.   
f.Name !=  "value__"  && // Field named 'value__' are relative to enumerations and the IL code never explicitely uses them.  
!f.HasAttribute("NDepend.Attributes.IsNotDeadCodeAttribute".AllowNoMatch()) &&   
!f.IsGeneratedByCompiler   // If you don't want to link NDepend.API.dll, you can use your own IsNotDeadCodeAttribute and adapt this rule.
select f
```